# How to remove a string and move it to the back of the string

Tags: ruby, regex, string, match

I have a string:

```
str = "AB asdfsa"
```

that matches the regular expression:

```
/^([A-Z][A-Z][[:space:]])[A-Z]/i
```

How do I take the part that matches between the parentheses and then move it to the end of the string? My desired output for the above would be a string:

```
"asdfsa AB"
```

Similarly, if there were a string:

```
"BC ffff eeee"
```

I want the result to be:

```
"ffff eeee BC"
```

I thought the `match?` keyword would allow me to extract that portion, but it only returns `true`/`false`:

```
str.match?(/^([A-Z][A-Z])[[:space:]][A-Z]/i) # => true
```

Comment: Note: With Ruby it's important to use `\A` and `\z` instead of the conventional `^` and `$`. The latter are anchored to any `\n` character that ends up in your input which can cause unpredictable or undesired results.

Comment: @tadman I think it is *important* to understand the difference. Sometimes `^` and `$` are the correct terminations.

Comment: @engineersmnky Absolutely! It's just trouble if out of habit you use `^` by default, as in with JavaScript, Perl, Python, etc.

Comment: I think you can do all with a single regex: `str.sub(/\A([A-Z][A-Z])([[:space:]]+)([A-Z].*)/m, '\3\2\1')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's `\1` not `$1` in Ruby, but you do have a good point.

Comment: @tadman: I know, I tested at regex101. Just a copy/paste thing

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [Rubular](http://rubular.com) is a good Ruby-specific testing tool, similar idea. Another useful tool.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm just adding a link to it for anyone curious about how Ruby handles regular expressions. Not suggesting you don't know about it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do this with a regular expression? It can be done much more simply without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Replace `match` with `split` then call `reverse.join(' ')`:

```
str = 'AB sdjfiosjdf'
str.split(/^([A-Z][A-Z])[[:space:]]/i).reverse.join(' ')
=> 'sdjfiosjdf AB'
```

Comment: THis isn't quite working.  If my string is "AB OAK CREEK" then running str.split(/^([A-Z][A-Z])[[:space:]][A-Z]/i).reverse.join(' ') produces "AK CREEK AB " (notice the "O" is missing in front of the word "OAK")

Comment: Edited to: `str.split(/^([A-Z][A-Z])[[:space:]]/i).reverse.join(' ')`. The Regex was also matching the next capital

Comment: Also for the record this won't work if there is anything before the first AZ. Should this work for `"aaa FF bbb"` => `"aaa bbb FF"` or would it always be at the beginning?

Comment: No it shoudn't switch for the "aaa FF" case, so your new answer work sperfectly.

Comment: @Natalia: Note that the `[A-Z]` in `/^([A-Z][A-Z])[[:space:]][A-Z]/i` might be important: what whodini9 suggests will match `CC 111` and your regex would not match it.

Comment: also this appends an extra space in the end because the regex is matching [[:space:]]. If you care, append `.rsrtip`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a single-regex solution to use with `sub`:

```
def swap_parts(s)
    s.sub(/\A([A-Z][A-Z])([[:space:]]+)([A-Z].*)/im, '\3\2\1')
end

swap_parts('AB asdfsa')    # => asdfsa AB
swap_parts('BC ffff eeee') # => ffff eeee BC
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/C2aelQ)

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of a string
- `([A-Z][A-Z])` (or `([A-Z]{2})`) - (*Group 1*) 2 ASCII letters (case insensitively, since `i` modifier is used)
- `([[:space:]]+)`  - (*Group 2*) 1 or more whitespaces
- `([A-Z].*)`  - (*Group 3*) an ASCII letter and any 0+ characters (since `m` modifier is passed, `.` now matches line break characters as well.

The replacement pattern inserts the captured parts in the reverse order: first Group 3 is used, then Group 2 value is appended and finally Group 3 comes in.

Comment: If, as in the examples, the substring to be moved to the end ends with a single space, you could of course simplify to two capture groups: `s.sub(/\A([A-Z][A-Z])[[:space:]]+([A-Z].*)/im, '\2 \1')`. I do like solutions that manipulate strings with conversion to an array and back.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are fine but they don't solve every problem. If you're always splitting by words and rotating the resulting array, then it's much simpler and faster to do just that, `split.rotate`:

```
[
  'AB asdfsa',
  'BC ffff eeee'
].map { |s| s.split.rotate.join(' ') }
# => ["asdfsa AB", "ffff eeee BC"]
```

Or:

```
[
  'AB asdfsa',
  'BC ffff eeee'
].map { |s| s.split(' ', 2).rotate.join(' ') }
# => ["asdfsa AB", "ffff eeee BC"]
```

Or:

```
[
  'AB asdfsa',
  'BC ffff eeee'
].map { |s| s.split(' ', 2).reverse.join(' ') }
# => ["asdfsa AB", "ffff eeee BC"]
```

`split` will be slower than `split(' ', 2)` for long strings because the first will walk the entire string splitting on whitespace, which can create a long array. The later will only find the first occurrence of whitespace then will return:

```
require 'fruity'

str = ['AB', ['asdfsa'] * 100].join(' ')

compare do
  split_rotate { str.split.rotate.join(' ') }
  split_2_rotate { str.split(' ', 2).rotate.join(' ') }
  split_2_reverse { str.split(' ', 2).reverse.join(' ') }
end

# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 3 seconds.
# >> split_2_reverse is similar to split_2_rotate
# >> split_2_rotate is faster than split_rotate by 22x ± 1.0
```

Regular expressions won't run as quickly because they're having to do a lot more work:

```
require 'fruity'

str = ['AB', ['asdfsa'] * 100].join(' ')

compare do
  split_rotate { str.split.rotate.join(' ') }
  split_2_rotate { str.split(' ', 2).rotate.join(' ') }
  split_2_reverse { str.split(' ', 2).reverse.join(' ') }
  victor { str.sub(/\A([A-Z][A-Z])([[:space:]]+)([A-Z].*)/im, '\3\2\1') }
  whodini9 { str.split(/^([A-Z][A-Z])[[:space:]]/i).reverse.join(' ') }
  engineersmnky { /^(?<first_two>[A-Z]{2})[[:space:]](?<rest>.+)/i.match(str).captures.reverse.join(' ') }
end

# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 4 seconds.
# >> split_2_rotate is similar to split_2_reverse
# >> split_2_reverse is faster than victor by 7x ± 1.0
# >> victor is similar to whodini9 (results differ: asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa AB vs asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa AB )
# >> whodini9 is similar to engineersmnky (results differ: asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa AB  vs asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa asdfsa AB)
# >> engineersmnky is faster than split_rotate by 3x ± 1.0
```

Even on short strings regular expressions have a disadvantage due to the startup time for the regular expression engine.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like

```
def swap_first_two(str)
  reg_exp = /^(?<first_two>[A-Z]{2})[[:space:]](?<rest>.+)/i
  reg_exp.match(str).captures.reverse.join(' ')
end
```

This should work for you OP use case and the commented use case e.g.

```
swap_first_two('AB asdfsa')
#=> "asdfsa AB"
swap_first_two('AB OAK CREEK')
#=> "OAK CREEK AB"
```

Also it appears (at least in basic benchmarks) to be slightly more performant to use `Regexp#match` and `MatchData#captures` than `String#split`

Answer (score 0):

Converting a string to an array, manipulating the array and then converting it back to a string is for me always a last resort. I have no good reason for that; the conversion dance just seems a bit brutish to me. I figure that if something can be done by merely manipulating the string, that's generally the way to go. I've taken the regular expression as a given:

```
r = /^([A-Z][A-Z][[:space:]])[A-Z]/i
```

You could write:

```
str = "AB asdfsa"
str.sub(r, '') << ' ' << $1[0..-2]
  #=> "sdfsa AB"
```

or

```
n = str.match(r).end(0)
  #=> 4
"%s %s" % [str[n..-1], str[0,n-2]]
  #=> "sdfsa AB"
```

Note that these work with any capture group that ends with a space. @Wiktor's answer also just manipulates the string.